# How to remove every alternate digits using unix

Tags: linux, unit-testing, unix, sed, awk

I have a file, this file contains a number like this 343434343434343434343434.

I want to remove every **alternate** digit

Input: `343434343434343434343434`

Desired Output:
`444444444444`

Comment: You mean to say 'every alternate digit', not subsequent digit, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you want to remove the first, third, fifth, ... character or the second, fourth, sixth ... character.

If the former,

```
$ echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqr' | perl -pe 's/.(?:(.)|$)/$1/g'
bdfhjlnpr
```

If the latter,

```
$ echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqr' | perl -pe 's/(.)(?:.|$)/$1/g'
acegikmoq
```

**[EDIT:** The `sed` commands in the previous version of the answer did not correctly handle input with an odd number of characters on a line.**]**

This is indifferent to the contents of the file *except* that it will preserve line boundaries.  If you want to delete newline characters that happen to be at odd (or even) offsets from the beginning of the file, you have to do something more sophisticated -- at that point I would probably reach for C, because it's easier to ignore line boundaries *comprehensibly* in C than with any of the shell utilities:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c1, c2;
    for (;;) {
        c1 = getchar();
        c2 = getchar();
#ifdef PRINT_THE_EVEN_CHARACTERS
        if (c1 == EOF || c2 == EOF) break;
        putchar(c2);
#else
        if (c1 == EOF) break;
        putchar(c1);
        if (c2 == EOF) break;
#endif
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than the C version, you can do the same with perl: perl -e '$/=\1; while( <> ) {  print if $i++ %2 } '  Use ++$i to get the odd characters.

Comment: Oh, that's cute.  I wasn't aware you could set `$/` to anything but a string, so I was about to nitpick that that only worked on input not containing ASCII SOH characters... then I noticed the absence of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
<<<"3434343434343434343434343" sed 's/.4\?/4/g'
444444444444
```

Or more precisely:

```
<<<"3434343434343434343434343" sed 's/[[:digit:]][^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]\?\)/\1/g'
444444444444
```

Comment: That first one doesn't work, there are too many fields in the 's' command

Comment: What is this `<<<` of which you speak?

Comment: @SiegeX I edited the first answer by hand after adding the second and put `/` instead of a `\\`, answer now corrected.

Comment: @Zack `<<<` is a here-string in a bash read about it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections).

Answer (score 0):

You can just:

```
sed -i 's/3//g' thefile
```

Remove the `-i` option to test first.

Comment: Hi fge, That 4 is an example. In middle number 3 also will come. if i use sed it will replace that also. thanks for your response

Comment: OK, can you clarify what you want to achieve? Edit your question so that someone can provide an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an affinity for `awk`

`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)printf $i}END{print ""}' FS=""`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 3434343434 | 
    dd cbs=2 conv=unblock 2>/dev/null |
    cut -c1|
    tr -d "\n" ; echo 
33333
```